# Get all materials of parent and its children in an array except for few

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting all materials from the parent and its children and storing it in an array. I want to however ignore few gameObjects from the list to be added. Can I add a string as the gameObject's name to be ignored so that except these gameObject, everything gets added?

Another thing is, how do I get all and each material from each gameObject? Few gameObjects have 5 and others have only 1. With the below code, I could only receive only one material from each gameObject.

```
    public Renderer[] allChildRenderers;
    public Material[] allMaterials;
    public string[] GameObjects_ToIgnore;

   void Start () {

        allChildRenderers = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer> ();
        allMaterials = new Material[allChildRenderers.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < allChildRenderers.Length; i++) {
           
                allMaterials[i] = allChildRenderers[i].GetComponent<Renderer> ().material;
            
        }

    }

 }
```

Comment: How did you even compiled this? **allMaterials[i]** returns a **material** but **Renderer().materials** return an array of materials (Material[]).

Comment: @SeLeCtRa yes it should be ```GetComponent<Renderer> ().material;``` But I want to get all the materials from each game object. So for example, I had mentioned that.

Comment: You should change **allMaterials** array to **List<Material[]> allMaterials**. Then use allMaterial.add(Renderer.materials)

Comment: @SeLeCtRa Okay I will try your method. Also how do I ignore a gameObject with the string? So that those gameObjects are not added?

Comment: Just use if(Renderer.gameObject.name != "ignoredName") { allMaterials.add(Renderer.materials); }

Comment: @SeLeCtRa I am using your solution by using the List and defining it like this ```allMaterials.Add (allChildRenderers.GetComponent<Renderer> ().materials);```. Unfortunately I am getting an error - 'Renderer[]' does not contain a definition for 'GetComponent' and no accessible extension method 'GetComponent' accepting a first argument of type 'Renderer[]' could be found.

Comment: You should not use GetComponent in array, you should use it in its child. Also, please update your question, I am really not sure what are you typing now.

Comment: I have updated my question. Could you please provide a solution as an answer?

Comment: In your question body, you ask for all childeren materials but in your code you look for main material of Renderer. Can you clarify what you want to achive as final

Comment: @SeLeCtRa I want to receive all the materials from all the children gameObjects (including the parents).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to ignore some GameObjects, you should use **tags**, which is a little harder to change than the name of the GameObjects themselves (this means your code may break if you change the name of the GameObject, as for the tag, you won't be changing frequently). Give the objects that should be ignored a new tag to indicate it.

[image]

```
for (int i = 0; i < allChildRenderers.Length; i++) { 
    if(allChildRenderers[i].gameObject.CompareTag("ignored_tag")) continue;
    allMaterials[i] = allChildRenderers[i].material;        
}
```

---

There is also a little ambiguity in your code:

```
allMaterials[i] = allChildRenderers[i].GetComponent<Renderer> ().material;
```

You are calling `GetComponent<Renderer>` in an object that is already a Renderer (`allChildRenderers[i]`). You should just call

```
allMaterials[i] = allChildRenderers[i].material;
```

---

As for the multiple materials in the same object, use `allChildRenderers[i].materials` to get the array of materials the object is using. `allChildRenderers[i],material` returns just the first material, while `allChildRenderers[i].materials` return the array with all of the used materials.

---

Try this:

First, change `allMaterials` for a list instead of array:

```
public List<Material> allMaterials = new List<Material>();
```

Then, try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allChildRenderers.Length; i++) { 
    if(allChildRenderers[i].gameObject.CompareTag("ignored_tag")) continue;
    foreach(Material mat in allChildRenderers[i].materials)
        allMaterials.Add(mat);        
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel. I di use materials in my code earlier but I get error ```Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Material[]' to 'UnityEngine.Material'```

Comment: You are probably setting `allMaterials[i] = allChildRenderers[i].materials`, which cannot be done.

Comment: You must guarantee that the length of `allMaterials` array is the sum of all materials of all objects. Then, you should put each material of `allChildRenderers[i].materials` in a single slot of `allMaterials`.

Comment: Yes exactly. So how do I fix this?

Comment: I added a possible fix in the end of the answer.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
List<string> excludedNames;

int materialIndex = 0;

for (Renderer currRenderer in allChildRenderers){
    
    if(!exludedNames.Contains(currRenderer.gameObject.name)){

        foreach(Material currMaterial in currRenderer.materials){

           allMaterials[materialIndex] = currMaterial;
           materialindex++;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT if allMaterials is supposed to have an entry per Renderer, it should be Material[][] or Renderer[]

```
Material[][] allMaterials;

List<string> excludedNames;

int rendererIndex = 0;

for (Renderer currRenderer in allChildRenderers){
    
    
    if(!exludedNames.Contains(currRenderer.gameObject.name)){
        
        int materialIndex = 0;
        foreach(Material currMaterial in currRenderer.materials){

           allMaterials[rendererIndex][materialIndex] = currMaterial;
           materialindex++;
        }

        rendererIndex++;
    }

   
}
```

Comment: allMaterials array length is Renderer count. But you are using Renderer.materials as input. It will throw error unless every Renderer only has 1 material, which is not the case.

Comment: Well should me Material[][] then, but i will just create a correction if thats the point

Comment: You should add parents material too. With GetComponent<Renderer>().materials. Then your answer is solution.

Comment: Sorry but it is not working. I even added foreach instead of for in your code. But the materials are not getting selected.

Comment: Selectra, GetComponentsInChildren also returns component in the gameObject it is called on.

Comment: Richard, Do you get an exception? Could you maybe debug and check which scopes are skipped?

Comment: @Malthe I will update my code that I have used from yours in my question.

Comment: I just dont think you can see two dimensional arrays in the inspector even though they exists (correct me if i am wrong) just like you cant see dictionaries. I made a correction, you should only increment the rendererindex if the if-statement is true. Could you try printing the dimensions of the array after the method has run. I think they are added, but just not visible in the inspector

Comment: @Malthe Even I think one cannot see it in inspector window. Instead I used List as given as an answer by another user. That works much better.

Comment: @Richard yes and you could easily add all the materials to a list, but if you want the materials from each renderer to be inserted together rather than just all materials mixed together, you would need a List<List<Material>> for that, so each List<Material> contains the materials from a single renderer and the overrall list contains all these lists. This should also be visible in the inspector

Comment: Woah a list within a list? I have never seen something like this before. Except that we can also create a struct and then add objects inside that.

Comment: You could do that, but it really depends on what you need.